# Accessing configuration value of vscode extension in task

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I am setting up a build task in visual studio code for an Arduino sketch. The command is defined as
`"command": "arduino-cli upload -p ${config:arduino.port} -v --fqbn arduino:avr:mega ${workspaceFolder}",`
where the ${workspaceFolder} is determined correctly (is this referred to as 'interpolated'?) but I would also like to access the COM port that has been set for the Arduino extension. However, the line above cannot be resolved becaues 'the setting arduino.port not found'. The command works if I hardcode the COM port. The port value is set in .vscode/arduino.json. I have tried ${arduino.port}, ${input:arduino.port}, ${command:arduino.port} without any luck.

More generally put, I would like to access the configuration value of an extension in a build task, such that I can simply copy tasks.json between projects or use it as a global build task (which I don't believe is supported yet). Any pointers on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my syntax was in the right direction - as a test I tried using `${config:python.pythonPath}` which is substituted correctly. So the format is correct but it appears that it is not possible to substitute user and workspace settings (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_common-questions). I presume that the port is indeed categorised as a workspace setting as it is located in .vscode/arduino.json in the workspace direction. It seems I will have to make do with a hardcoded value